# Shall I expect faster boot when I boot my system with run level 1

Tags: init, runlevel

I understand that when I set runlevel as 1, my system will boot with very basic set of commands. Does that mean the system will boot faster as compared to run level 5 or 3?

Comment: Why don't you try it out by measuring with a stopwatch. If you have difficulty processing the results ask on [statistics.se]. The results completely depend on what is defined for what runlevel. What are you trying to achieve? Giveaway: the fastest way to get your computer in a non-productive state is to not boot it all.

Answer (score 1):

It's maintenance mode. Obviously less services and hence a faster boot. Check /etc/rc1.d/ directory for services that will be started as part of this runlevel and services that will be killed when you switch to runlevel 1 from another runlevel.

Answer (score 0):

It will boot faster, but you might find that you can't do anything useful.  Networking will be absent as will many other system services.  Most notably, depending on your distro and setup, you might find that your root filesystem is mounted read-only.

If you want to work on the root filesystem in single-user mode and you find it mounted read-only, you can do

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
```

Comment: The root filesystem is typically read-write well before the switch to runlevel 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes probably but it will not be usable, because it needs to initialize several service to be able interact with network for example.
So yes it will boot faster with reduce set of instruction available.

You can find a basic description of which runlevel will allow you on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Linux)